# Investigating the behaviour of matrix $A^{k}$ as $k$ increases indefinitely ($k \to \infty$ )

Tags: matrices

This is my first post here in this forum. If anything wrong, please tell me.
My problem is this: "Given the matrix $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac12 & \frac13 \\
\frac14 & 1 & \frac15 \\
\frac16 & \frac17 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and we use matrix multiplication to multiply matrix $A$ with $A$ for $k$ times, so we've got: $A^{k}$.
Then, let $k$ increase indefinitely and observe the behaviour of matrix $A^{k}$."

I have tried this problem on MATLAB by putting in large values of $k$. The result MATLAB returned was like this: $$\begin{pmatrix}
\inf & \inf & \inf \\
\inf & \inf & \inf \\
\inf & \inf & \inf \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It seems that as $k$ increases, the matrix $A^{k}$ just goes to infinity. However, I still have doubts about this result. I think that it should have converged to some special values like $1$ or $0$. Could anyone clear out my mind about this?

PS: This is the image of MATLAB: [The value $n$ here is $k$ and in the code I put in the value $10^{6}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QcAu.png)

This is my code used to calculate:

```
n=input('Enter number n:');
A=[1 1/2 1/3; 1/4 1 1/5; 1/6 1/7 1];
B=A^n;
format long
disp(B)
```

Comment: Have you tried [diagonalization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Matrix+Diagonalization&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22Matrix+Diagonalization%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22MatrixOperations%22%2C+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B1%2C1%2F2%2C1%2F3%7D%2C%7B1%2F4%2C1%2C1%2F5%7D%2C%7B1%2F6%2C1%2F7%2C1%7D%7D%22)?

Comment: No sir, i haven't tried that.